# Ceiling Fan Light Only Works when Fan is On

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

I have a ceiling fan & light that is controlled by a wall switch. Recently, I went to turn the lights on and they flickered but didn't turn on. The fan works fine.

I decided to replace the switch with a new fan control and dimmer and the connections lined up with red, black & white wires. I turned the power back on and the fan worked - lights didn't.

So, I decided to replace the light kit and the connection worked fine (one white & one black). Turned the power back on and same issue.

The next day I woke up and switched both the Fan and Lights all the way on and THEY BOTH WORKED! Essentially, I learned that if the fan is turned up all the way - the lights work.

Any idea on why this is and what I can do so that they both work?

One PS to this - I noticed that there is a quiet slight buzzing to the switch when it is turned on.

Comment: Can you give us photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: I think I solved it. I added my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution that worked.

SWITCH  --------->  OUTLET

Yellow  ------------>  Black

Red--------------->  Red

Black ------------> White

[image: This was the solution.]